# Asp.NET 5 Dependency Injection - Passing Arguments at Runtime

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection

How to resolve a service instance by using IServiceCollection in Asp.NET 5 app and passing another service instance to a constructor?

Similar to what StructureMap has: http://structuremap.github.io/resolving/passing-arguments-at-runtime?

Answer (score 0):

IServiceCollection does not have named dependencies. So you'll have to replace the default container. Good news is that if you like StructureMap, they have a NuGet package for DNX projects now, here: https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap.dnx

Please read the example of how to get StructureMap working in your ASP.NET Core (formerly known as ASP.NET 5) project.

If you want more ideas about what the architecture should look like with named dependencies I have an example [here](https://dannyvanderkraan.wordpress.com/2015/06/29/real-world-example-of-dependency-injection-based-on-run-time-values/).

Comment: Hi Danny, I'm building a NuGet (using Class Library (Package) project) and if put a dependency to SM then project referencing my Nuget will lost a freedom to use whatever DI/IoC container they want.

Comment: I don't think so. Because the project referencing your NuGet package will also have to be a DNX project, which means they can all share IServiceCollection/IServiceProvider. Look at the last line of the example: return container.GetInstance<IServiceProvider>();